# How to securely access the database while running selenium tests in Browserstack

Tags: selenium-webdriver, database-connection, browserstack

I have a set of selenium tests that can run on browserstack. They currently use hardcoded test data but I would like to move away from that and create test data from within the test.

However, the challenge I'm facing is creating the test data involves running sql queries at some point. As these tests are going to be running on browserstack I do not want to expose the database connections to a third party.

I'm looking for a secure way to connect and update the database while the tests are running on browserstack. I've tried researching online but did not find much help. Can anyone provide me with a solution?